# how to make migration for custom module from odoo 15 to 16?

Tags: attributeerror, odoo-15, odoo-16

i try to make migration for a custom report from odoo 15 to 16 i have now error on view side and thier is now bugs but when press the buttoun i got this message :

```
AttributeError: 'stock.picking' object has no attribute 'move_lines'
```

i tried to make migration from odoo 15 to 16 to custom report that update the effective date with date that enter in wizard view but  i got this error message when i press the buttoun :

```
AttributeError: 'stock.picking' object has no attribute 'move_lines'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a *stock.picking* object, `move_lines` field name changed to `move_ids` in Odoo 16.0

Table relation is still the same. So you need to change your code with a new technical field to resolve that error.

Comment: Thanks, I change the field name to move_ids and its works